# Rearrange the multi-level XML tree to a single-level via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert the following XML text:

```
<root>
    <Header>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Line>
            <LineID>10</LineID>
        </Line>
        <LineGroup>
            <LineID>11</LineID>
            <Line>
                <LineID>12</LineID>
            </Line>
            <Line>
                <LineID>13</LineID>
            </Line>
        </LineGroup>
    </Header>
</root>
```

to the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <LineID>10</LineID>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <LineID>11</LineID>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <LineID>12</LineID>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <LineID>13</LineID>
</row>
```

The LineGroup element seems to be an obstacle for me.

Help is appreciated greatly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not well formed xml (so I expect `<root>` element to be present). Try following script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/Header" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="ID" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//LineID">
            <row>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ID" />
                </ID>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are quite right-I missed the root element. Thank you. It seems that I simplified the input more than I intended to. What shall I do with the following input file with additional attributes - Desc etc, that must be output?
<root><Header>
<ID>1000</ID>
<Line>
<LineID>10</LineID>
<Desc>Door</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Line>
<LineGroup>
<LineID>11</LineID>
<Desc>Set</Desc>
<TotalAmount>150.00</TotalAmount>
<Line>
<LineID>12</LineID>
<Desc>Item 1</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Line>
<Line>
<LineID>13</LineID>
<Desc>Item 2</Desc>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Line>
</LineGroup>
</Header>
</root>

Comment: My apologies for not formatting the comment. I am new on this site.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I followed your advice to use the "LineID" as the anchor and figured out what to do next.